# java program ignoring else if statement [NOOBIE]

Tags: java

```
public class IfElseIf {
    /**operators for if statements
     * Less than (<)
     * Greater Than (>)
     * Less than or Equal To (<=)
     * Greater Than or Equal To (>=)
     * And (&&)
     * Not (!)
     * Or (||) 
     * Has the value (==)
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int user = 50;

        if (user <= 21){
            System.out.println("User is 21 or younger.");
        }


        else if (user > 21 && user < 60){
            System.out.println("User is between 21 and 59.");
         //you can have as many else if statements as you want.
        }


        else if (user == 50 || user == 55){
            System.out.println("User is either 50 or 55");
        }


        else {
            System.out.println("User is older than 60");
        }/**else signifies that any value outside of the 
        *parameters set should show this message.
        */
    }
}
```

I am new to Java I am trying to learn java. This is my first day of learning how to code. I am trying to run this program, so that it will show the message for the second else if statement, but when I run the program by changing the user variable to 55 it still shows up with the message for the first else if statement. Why is it ignoring the second else if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `if-else` statements, the first statement being true gets executed, while the others get ignored (even if they may be true as well).
Having the value '55', the first `else-if` statement, `(user > 21 && user < 60)`  is true (21 < 55 < 60) that's why it gets executed.

If you want to (force to) check the second condition as well you might change `else-if` to a simple `if`, so a new `if-else` "cycle" gets started again.

Comment: Thank you! I feel I should have figured that out on my own haha. I will keep this in mind. Thank you again!

Comment: I don't know why my answer got downvoted, but if it is because my answer instead of this person's one got accepted by the inquirer, if feel deeply sorry for you, but you probably haven't understand the concept of downvoting/stackoverflow. It's a community to help each other! ...

Answer (score 0):

Because condition statements stop immediately when find the first match.

So, the second `if else` covers range from 22 to 59.

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly!

Answer (score 0):

In your code,

"else if (user > 21 && user < 60)"

condition is satisfied first when you use user = 55. so, next else if condition will be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

The order of your else if block is important. Since 55 is > 21 and < 60, the first else if block is executed and the program exit your else if statments. So the second one is ingored. Put it before the "else if (user > 21 && user < 60){" and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

For the value 55 the below condition is always satisfied and hence it will not go inside the next else-if statement even if it holds true.

```
else if (user > 21 && user < 60){
                    System.out.println("User is between 21 and 59.");
                 //you can have as many else if statements as you want.
                }
```

If you reverse their order it will work as expected.

```
else if (user == 50 || user == 55){
            System.out.println("User is either 50 or 55");
        }

 else if (user > 21 && user < 60){
            System.out.println("User is between 21 and 59.");
         //you can have as many else if statements as you want.
        }
```

You can also modify it as shown below:

```
else if (user > 21 && user < 50){
            System.out.println("User is between 21 and 49.");
         //you can have as many else if statements as you want.
        }


        else if (user == 50 || user == 55){
            System.out.println("User is either 50 or 55");
        }

        else if (user >50 && user< 55){
            System.out.println("User is between 51 to 54");
        }
        else
{
System.out.println("User is older than 55");
}
```